# Full drive encryption using usb mouse reciever as decryption key

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

The title says it all. Is there a way to have full drive encryption that would decrypt if my usb wireless mouse receiver was plugged in? Primarily using linux. Have a Windows partition.

Comment: This sounds like an awful idea, you could probably use the hardware ID or something if you have access to that when you are decrypting the drive. The issue is that anyone could plug in your device, read the hardware ID, and then spoof it on another device. As far as I know this kind of thing doesn't exist, because it's a bad idea.

Comment: Lol I didn't think too far into this just didn't want to type in two passwords. I guess it is a horrible idea.

Comment: Given the recent "oh duh!" revelation that most USB devices have firmware that can be modified.  Using the hardware id for decrypting doesn't seem like a good idea. Besides wireless mouse recievers are far from secure.